# Facebook like button frame inside a fixed footer

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook-like, sticky-footer

I want to get something like this

[image]

but I currently have this

[image]

I have tried some things to solve it but I am getting nowhere, What can I do?

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xjJsk/3/)

I have some definitions like:

```
#footer {
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: #000;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 12px;
}
```

and this iframe

```
<iframe src="FACEBOOKURL&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=20" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100%; height:20px;" allowTransparency="true">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use float left.

```
<div style="float:left">text</div>
<div style="float:left">iframe</div>
```

make sure that iframe width can adjust on your space

check this - http://jsfiddle.net/im4aLL/xjJsk/10/

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to `float` the elements too. A simpler solution is just remove the `width:100%` for the iframe.

Markup:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com/Eurekavi&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=20" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden;  height:20px;" allowTransparency="true">
```

Working Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/xjJsk/23/

Comment: so is it better to get rid of the width:100% for posterior uses?